# let $L = \{\langle M \rangle \mid M \text { is a TM, } \forall x \in L(M), x^R \notin L(M)\}$. Prove/disprove $L\in RE \backslash R$

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, turing-machines

let $L = \{\langle M \rangle  \mid M \text { is a TM, } \forall x \in L(M), x^R \notin L(M)\}$

($x^R$ is the reverse of $x$)

I need to determine and prove whether $L\in R , L\in RE \backslash R, \overline{L}\in RE\backslash R $ or none of them.

I'm pretty sure $L\in RE \backslash R$ because I think I know how to prove it's undecidable, but I'm having a hard time proving it's recognizable.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why would proving it's undecidable make you pretty sure that $L\in RE\setminus R$, as opposed to $\overline L\in RE\setminus R$ ?

Comment: @AndreasBlass Is it possible that $L\notin R$ and also $\overline{L} \notin R$?

Comment: Oh yeah you are right. It's very possible - it will always be like that.

Comment: So basically the question is asking if there's an algorithm (or semi-algorithm) to decide if a given TM has the property that: if it accept a certain string, then it does not accept the reversal of that string. Right?

Comment: @AlexVong Yes. I think I know how to solve it with supervised execution (proving $\overline{L} $ is recognizable).

Comment: @sheldonzy Yes, I think it can be done with asynchronous process and callback (in programming terminology). Should I write it as an answer?

Comment: @sheldonzy Also, I think $L$ is non-recognizable. But I am still searching for a reduction.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've mentioned that you know how to prove $\overline{L}$ is recognizable, I will only prove $L$ is not recognizable.

Recall that $L$ is decidable if and only if both $L$ and $\overline{L}$ are recognizable. Therefore, it suffices to show $L$ is undecidable.

Suppose for contradiction that $L$ is decidable, then there exists a decider $D$ for $L$. With $D$, the following algorithm can decide if a given TM $M$ accepts $\varepsilon$:

> Given TM encoding $\langle M \rangle$
>
> Let $M'$ be the following TM:
>     Given input string $s$
>     If $s = \varepsilon$:
>         Simulate $M$ with $\varepsilon$
>     else:
>         Reject
>
> Simulate $D$ with $\langle M' \rangle$
> If $D$ rejects then accept else reject

This contradicts the fact that whether a given TM $M$ accepts $\varepsilon$ is undecidable. Therefore, $L$ is undecidable and hence $\overline{L} \in RE \setminus R$

The above algorithm works because $D$ accepts $\langle M \rangle$ if $``\forall s \in \Sigma^* \ M \text{ accepts } s \implies M \text{ does not accept } s^R"$, and rejects $\langle M \rangle$ if $``\exists s \in \Sigma^* \text{ such that } M \text{ accepts both } s \text{ and } s^R"$.